# wp super cache update cache only on post update

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I have set a cache time of 3600 seconds on WP super Cache

Is there any way to leave it longer than that, and only update the cache file
when the post is updated? So it doesnt have to rebuild the cache every 3600 seconds for each post?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the WP Super Cache admin page, make sure under `Advanced` that "Clear all cache files when a post or page is published or updated" is checked.

Then set the cache timeout (under "Expiry Time & Garbage Collection") to `86400` seconds, and set the scheduler to "Clock : Once Yearly".

OR, if you set the cache timeout to `0`, this will disable garbage collection so the cache can only be cleared manually.

Comment: If I set cachetimeout =0, will the cache be cleared even if I checked "clear all cache files when post is published/updated"?

Comment: `0` disables garbage collection, meaning it won't ever check to see if your cache is expired.